# Replace black boot screen with Purple ( default )

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, bootloader

I used to have Gnome and Cinnamon on my laptop. Maybe because of that, the boot screen has changed to a black one than default Purple boot screen. I have since then upgraded to 16.04 from 14.04 and everything was good.

But recently, I am facing frequent boot failure. The boot screen flashes, goes transparent and shows some terminal like activities in the background. In the end, mostly it will say some process failed and I never get to the GUI.

This is happening so frequently that I am not able to use my PC at all. Will replacing black boot screen with Purple solve this problem ? If no, kindly suggest a solution for the same. Thanks.

PS: I now use Unity alone with 16.04